# jquery: append to textbox on document load

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, append

Using jQuery's plugin architecture, I have in my js file a line of code that appends a simple "div" element to a textbox. The task seems so simple, but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

A snippet from my html file

```
<div style="margin-top:50px">
    Search: <input id="searchbox" type="text" /><br />
</div>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#searchbox').testplugin();
})
</script>
```

This is from the testplugin.js file

```
init : function(options)
{
    // some initialization

    // iterate through all the jquery objects
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).append('<div>Sample Text</div>');
    });
}
```

At this point, I'm sure that $(this) refers to the correct object (I've tried alerting the id). Also, when I try to do a "view source" in Firefox, I also see the newly-appended div (but not in the actual GUI). However, in Internet Explorer, I am getting an "Unexpected call to method or propery access" error.

What am I doing wrong here? Or what should I do to make this work?

Thanks!
Erwin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified my code to use after() instead of append()

```
init : function(options)
{
    // some initialization

    // iterate through all the jquery objects
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).after('<div>Sample Text</div>');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Erwin, I'm fairly sure that per spec - you cannot put a div element inside of an input element. This is probably the source of your IE error & the reason you do not see anything in your browser when it loads up.

Try doing .val('test'); instead of append() & you'll probably encounter working code, same for .addClass('yourcssclass'); or any other "lawful" DOM operation.

Comment: "I'm fairly sure that per spec - you cannot put a div element inside of an input element" LOL awesome.

Comment: i must have misunderstood the append() function. i thought this was going to add a sibling next to the target element.

Comment: I guess what I was looking for is the after() method. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

```
init : function(options)
{
// some initialization

// iterate through all the jquery objects
return this.each(function() {
    $(this).val('Sample Text');
});
}
```

this code will help if you are trying to make the text inside the textbox '**Sample Text**'
your plugin will still work on elemets such as `div`,`a`etc...

Comment: Thanks for the help man. I actually found the solution. I was wrong in assuming that append() creates a sibling. As I've mentioned above, I changed append() to after(), and it's ok now.